# How do I make other computers able to access my socket.io server

Tags: javascript

So I've been working on a chatroom project which runs on a *socket.io* server. I want to deploy the chat room app on the web and make it possible for other computer to access the page and send data to the server, but since my server is *localhost*, it is not possible for that to happen yet. Does anyone know how to how to make the server so it's able to run on the web and accessible from other computers?

Comment: Putting it on http://glitch.com/ is the easiest option.

Comment: Do you want to host it on your own computer or are you using a hosting company?

Comment: I didn't mean to type "how to" twice

Comment: Jonathan.Rosa, I am hosting it on my local machine

Comment: ggorlen, thanks for your advise, I'll take a look on the website.